# How do I change font for each line in a cell if it starts with a special character?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change font for each line in a multi-lined cell, if the line starts with "#" and "-".

My macro changes the font for the first instance of the special character and everything below it.
I need it to check if each line in a cell starts with the special character (i.e. # or -) and then change if true.

```vb
Dim i as Range
Dim POS As Long, Before As Long, After As Long

For Each i in Sheet(1).UsedRange.Columns(2).Cells
    POS = 0
    If InStr(1, i.text, "#") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, i.text, "#")
    If InStr(1, i.text, "-") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, i.text, "-")

    If POS > 0 Then
        Before = InStrRev(i.text,chr(10), POS)
        After = InStr(POS, i.text, vbNewline)

        With i.Characters(Start:=Before + 1, Length:=After - (Before + 1).font
            .Name = "Consolas"
            .Size = 12
       End With
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using split() to check each line individually:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, arr, ln, n As Long, pos As Long
    
    For Each c In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(2).Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(c.Value, vbLf) 'get an array of lines
            pos = 1                    'start point
            
            For n = 0 To UBound(arr)   'loop over the lines
                ln = arr(n)
                Debug.Print ln
                ' # must be escaped by wrapping in []
                If Trim(ln) Like "-*" Or Trim(ln) Like "[#]*" Then
                    With c.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=Len(ln)).Font
                        .Name = "Consolas"
                        .Size = 12
                    End With
                End If
                pos = pos + Len(ln) + 1 'move start point
            Next n
        End If 'has any value
    Next c
        
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI `Trim(ln) Like "-*" Or Trim(ln) Like "[#]*" Then` can be written as `Trim(ln) Like "[-#]*" Then` (to include a `-` in a character list it must be [first or last](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator))

Comment: @chrisneilsen - good point, thanks

Comment: @TimWilliams, Thank you this worked like a charm. how do I search a word "Note:" in the same way? I tried to use Instr() in the same format but it does not seen to work.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, Thank you.

Comment: May be `If Trim(ln) like "Note:*"` if you're expecting to find it at the start of a line, or `If Trim(ln) like "*Note:*"` if in the middle somewhere.

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yeah it does not seem to do the trick. I tried "[Note:]*" and it seem to work but it changed all the instances of N,o,t,e and ":" in a cell.

Comment: `[Note:]` will match any one of those characters so that's not what you want.   Can you post an example of the content for a single cell where you're having this problem?

Comment: `If Trim(ln) Like "[#-]*" Or Trim(ln) Like "Note:*" Then` is working for me, if the line start with "Note:"

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you. It is working for me too. A little tweak here and there did it. Really appreciate your help.